# how to call other plugins once custom post has been inserted

Tags: php, wp-insert-post, scripts

i built custom script to import woocommerce product using (wp_insert_post)  and i want to call other plugins to insert their data to each new products to db for example:

after inserting product if i opened that product and clicked update the yoast seo insert to db all required info like _yoast_wpseo_primary_product_brand and so on,  and  second example if during the insert the product stock was 0 woocommerce by default put the product in-stock till i click update .

i tried to call wp_update_post ( $post_id )  but nothing has been changed.

can you please advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't completely understand your question - maybe this will help:

```
wp_insert_post(array(
    // your woocomm post being inserted
));

// at insert, `save_post` will fire
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_plugin_save_post' , 10 , 3 );

function my_plugin_save_post($post_id, $post, $update) {

    // check other firing of this: if this is a revision, get real post ID
    if ( $parent_id = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) 
        $post_id = $parent_id;

    // you can condialize if you want to exicute on new posts (like `wp_insert_post`), or if you're UPDATEing a post
    if ($update) {
        // only run if post has been saved before

        // ------ example: you can UPDATE the `post` itself with ------

        // unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
        remove_action( 'save_post', 'my_plugin_save_post' );

        // update the post, which calls save_post again
        wp_update_post( 
            array( 
                'ID' => $post_id, 
                'post_status' => 'private' 
            ) 
        );

        // re-hook this function
        add_action( 'save_post', 'my_plugin_save_post' );

        // ------ example: or you can do post meta work ------

        if ($somthing == true)
            update_post_meta($post_id, ...

        // ------ example: or "call" other plugins ----

        wc_update_product_stock(...);

    } else {
        // only run if post is brand new
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks David that's exactly what am looking for.

and sorry for not being clear in my question :)